# Enforcing particular constraints when writing a MySQL schema file?

Tags: mysql, database, constraints

Here's the code I have so far:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS lab2;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS lab2;
USE lab2;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hotel (
  hotelNo CHAR(3) NOT NULL , -- Primary Key
  hotelName CHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
  city CHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (hotelNo)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS room (
  roomNo CHAR(3) NOT NULL , -- Primary key
  hotelNo CHAR(3) NOT NULL , -- References Hotel
  type CHAR(2) NOT NULL ,
  price NUMERIC(3) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (roomNo)
);

ALTER TABLE room ADD CONSTRAINT room_hotelNo
    FOREIGN KEY (hotelNo) REFERENCES hotel(hotelNo);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS booking(
  hotelNo CHAR(3) NOT NULL , -- references hotel
  guestNo NUMERIC(8) NOT NULL , -- references guest
  dateFrom DATE NOT NULL , -- primary key
  dateTo DATE NOT NULL ,
  roomNo CHAR(3) NOT NULL , -- references room
  PRIMARY KEY (dateFrom)
);

ALTER TABLE booking ADD CONSTRAINT booking_hotelNo
    FOREIGN KEY (hotelNo) REFERENCES hotel(hotelNo);
ALTER TABLE booking ADD CONSTRAINT booking_roomNo
    FOREIGN KEY (roomNo) REFERENCES room(roomNo);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS guest (
  guestNo NUMERIC(8) NOT NULL , -- primary key
  guestName CHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
  guestAddress CHAR(30),
  PRIMARY KEY (guestNo)
);

ALTER TABLE booking ADD CONSTRAINT booking_guestNo
    FOREIGN KEY (guestNo) REFERENCES guest(guestNo);
```

I want to add the following constraints, but I'm unsure on how to go about it:

dateFrom    must    be  no  later   than    dateTo.

Room    type    must    be  one of  'BS',   'BD',   'BF',   'S',    'D',    'F',    'LS',   'LD',   'LF'

Room    prices  are between 50  and 350.

Only    rooms   with    type    'LF'    can possibly    have    prices  greater than    300.

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL you won't be able to specify constraints such as `LF` has to have a price greater than 300 (You may want to check out another database like postgres: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/ddl-constraints.html).

MySQL supports 2 types of constraints:

- [Unique indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) (Which can cover multiple columns)
- [Enumerations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html) (Which aren't really constraints, but they have a way to ensure data can only be of a certain type.)